# Setting up CD for vNext app with new VSO build agent

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up continuous deployment for my vNext apps, using the new Visual Studio Online build agent.

Please note: I have excluded the `/wwwroot` folder from source control. The 'default` Grunt handles all CSS + JS concatenation + minification and places it into the folder. I've set up pre-build binding for this task, so you can just right-click-publish the app. That works fine, since the publish will do a build - which triggers the Grunt task to prepare the distribution.

However - the VSO build agent does not seem to trigger the Grunt task. Therefore the build server doesn't have any `/wwwroot` content and thus the deployment doesn't work.

How can I fix this? OR - should I just include the `/wwwroot` folder in source control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a full day of figuring this out - I've got a solution. However, I'm affraid this will only be a temporary solution. As soon as the new VSO build tasks are released, this will be a lot easier.

Here's what I did:

1. I started by installing the latest version of [Node](https://nodejs.org/) onto the build server, which seemed to speed things up and got rid of some strange warnings. Also - I updated to the latest version of the build agent ( [see bottom of this page how](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/windows#qa_windows_agent_powershell_version)). Check that Node is in the path and globally install bower and grunt ( `npm install -g bower` and `npm install -g grunt-cli` )
2. Then I started with a new build template from scratch in Visual Studio online, set the Git bindings correctly and added the first step: NPM Install ( add a step - select 'NPM Install' ). Set working directory to the folder of your  `.xproj`
3. Next step: Add a 'Grunt build' step. Point it at your `Gruntfile.js` + set working directory to the same directory. I'm running grunt task `build` because that came with the yeoman template. I modified so it outputs everything into the `/wwwroot` folder.
4. Add a 'Visual Studio Build'-step that builds the project bits. Add argument `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation=\"$(build.stagingDirectory)\"`

So, this is all pretty much 'out-of-the-box'. The next steps ( package the app + deploy it ) aren't. I suspect that in the future we'll have nice VSO build tasks that will make this easy to do. I had to fiddle around with the command line.
However, I turned out to be quite easy. If you set up the publishing from Visual Studio - you can see the commands it runs in the output  window. You want to re-create those commands in 2 command steps.

5. Add a command line step for command `C:\Users\Administrator\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6\bin\dnu.cmd`. Yes - it's now coupled to the DNX runtime - so that's not optimal. But we need the DNX Utility to package our app - hence the command arguments:
   `publish --out $(build.stagingDirectory) --configuration Release --wwwroot-out "wwwroot" --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6` ( again - just copied it from the output window of VS )

This will nicely package up the app into the `$(build.stagingDirectory)` folder. 
Next - get it up in the cloud.

6. Add the final 'command line' step with command: `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe` and argument `-source:IisApp='$(build.stagingDirectory)\wwwroot' -dest:IisApp='--something--',ComputerName='https://--something--.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd',UserName='$--something--',Password='--notsaying--',IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic' -verb:sync -enableLink:contentLibExtension  -retryAttempts:2`

NOTE: this assumes that you've set up publishing to the website. Go to the Azure portal - to your Azure website - and set up publishing. Download the publish profile XML file and you'll find these parameters inside. Also - all parameters are written in the Visual Studio output window ( except for password ).

This is working for me right now: Continuous Deployment of a vNext / ASP.NET 5 web app using the new Visual Studio Online (VSO) build agent.

[image: Build overview]